# react native element listItem.accordion

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-elements

//I am rendering an API response with the help of FLatlist but when I press the expand option it will open all the accordions.................

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import SearchBox from '../../components/SearchBox/SearchBox'
import { ListItem, Icon, Slider } from '@rneui/themed'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllPackages } from '../../feature/packageSlice'

const Rounds = () => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)

    const pack = useSelector(getAllPackages)
```

//flatlist render item

```
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <ListItem.Accordion
                content={
                    <>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title style={styles.header}>
                                {item.name}
                            </ListItem.Title>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </>
                }
                isExpanded={expanded}
               onPress={() => {
                    setExpanded(!expanded)
                }}
            >
                <View style={styles.card}>
                    <Text style={styles.font}>Water Supply Pressure</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ListItem.Accordion>
        )
    }
```

//main render

```
    return (
        <View>
                    <FlatList
                    data={pack}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}


export default Rounds
```

I want to open up the selected accordion only how can I achieve that, please help thanks...................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your code correctly and this is one component (not fraction of few) your problem is following:

`const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)`

This state variable is on top of your parent Component, so each rendered item points to it.
Therefore if you change it from any of your ListItem.Accordion, it will affect all of them.

**BUT**

If you change your renderItem to render Component. like this:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
           <AccordionListItem item={item}/>
        )
}
```

Then you can move this state inside AccordionListItem itself, so it will create unique instance for each unique instance of  component.

```
//imports
import React from ...

const AccordionListItem = ({item}) => {
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false) <========= !


return (
      <ListItem.Accordion
                content={
                    <>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title style={styles.header}>
                                {item.name}
                            </ListItem.Title>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </>
                }
                isExpanded={expanded}
               onPress={() => {
                    setExpanded(!expanded)
                }}
            >
                <View style={styles.card}>
                    <Text style={styles.font}>Water Supply Pressure</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ListItem.Accordion>
)
}

export default AccordionListItem ;
```